# Decomposition of tensor product of permutation representation of $S_n$.

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Please be kind to me - I'm a combinatorist so this question might be a bit naive...

If $U$ is the representation space of the permutation representation of $S_n$, is there any known decomposition into irreducibles of $U\otimes U$?

Cheers.

Comment: Do you mean $U$ is the irreducible representation corresponding to the partition $(n-1,1)$ or do you mean the reducible representation $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the permutation of coordinates?

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I believe the permutation representation refers to the reducible one, while the irreducible one is the standard representation.

Answer (score 3):

Let $V_{\lambda}$ be the irreducible representation corresponding to the integer partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots)$ of $n$. Then, as explained by Mike Earnest
$$
U=V_{(n)}\oplus V_{(n-1,1)}\ .
$$
since tensoring with the trivial representation $V_{(n)}$ does nothing, it's just a matter of computing some simple Kronecker coefficients which gives
$$
V_{(n-1,1)}\otimes V_{(n-1,1)}=
V_{(n)}\oplus V_{(n-1,1)}\oplus V_{(n-2,2)}\oplus V_{(n-2,1,1)}
$$
with the end result
$$
U\otimes U=2V_{(n)}\oplus 3 V_{(n-1,1)}\oplus V_{(n-2,2)}\oplus V_{(n-2,1,1)}
$$
where $2V_{(n)}$ means the module appreas with multiplicity 2, etc.

If interested in the explicit morphisms, then see [this article](http://www.ieja.net/files/papers/volume-10/Volume-9--2011/9-V10-2011.pdf) by Chipalkatti and Mohammed.